# Отправка почты Ларавел locallhost

Tags: php, laravel

env:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=gmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Controller

```
public function htmlEmail(){
        $data = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");
        Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) {
            $message->to('gmail2@yandex.ru', 'Tutorials Point')->subject
            ('Laravel HTML Testing Mail');
            $message->from('gmail@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi');
        });
        echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
    }
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "gmail@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
 534 5.7.9
```

Прошу помогите... я не знаю что делаю не так...

Двухэтапную авторизацию подключил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двухэтапную аутентификацию нужно отключить и включить Less secure app access в настройках google аккаунта.

Comment: Просто лучший! Спасибо большое! Вчера день убил...

Comment: @AlexandrRevnuk Рад был помочь. Удачи в изучении.